# Code 324 Not Valid Video and Status failed?

Tags: django, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to upload video through twitter API from my website. I scraped their github library code's async upload file for large files. I am uploading the data in chunks. This is the code:
(Note I am using static file size and chunks for the testing purpose would definitely appreciate a dynamic method suggestion)

```
    MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json'
    POST_TWEET_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'

    CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
    ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxx-xxx'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxx'

    VIDEO_FILENAME = request.FILES['video']
    VIDEO_SIZE = 59467

    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
                   client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                   resource_owner_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

    request_data = {
      'command': 'INIT',
      'media_type': 'video/mp4',
      'total_bytes': VIDEO_SIZE,
      'media_category': 'tweet_video'
    }

    req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    print req
    media_id = req.json()['media_id']

    print('Media ID: %s' % str(media_id))

    segment_id = 0
    bytes_sent = 0
    vid_file = VIDEO_FILENAME

    while bytes_sent < VIDEO_SIZE:
        chunk = vid_file.read(59467)
        print('APPEND')

        request_data = {
            'command': 'APPEND',
            'media_id': media_id,
            'segment_index': segment_id
        }

        files = {
            'media': chunk
        }

        req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, files=files, auth=oauth)

        if req.status_code < 200 or req.status_code > 299:
            print(req.status_code)
            print(req.text)

        segment_id = segment_id + 1
        bytes_sent = vid_file.tell()

        print('%s of %s bytes uploaded' % (str(bytes_sent), str(VIDEO_SIZE)))

    print('Upload chunks complete.')

    request_data = {
        'command': 'FINALIZE',
        'media_id': media_id,
        'media_category': 'tweet_video'
    }

    req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    print(req.json())

    processing_info = req.json().get('processing_info', None)
    print(req.status_code)

    time.sleep(5)

    request_data = {
        'status': 'I just uploaded a video with the @TwitterAPI.',
        'media_ids': req.json()['media_id_string'],
        'media_category': 'tweet_video'
    }

    req = requests.post(url=POST_TWEET_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    print(req.json())

    context = {
        'r': req
    }
    return render_to_response('dashboard/manage_content/display.html', context)
```

I am hit by the following error:

> {"errors":[{"code":324,"message":"Not valid video"}]}
> I am uploading a mp4 file of 1.6 mb size. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: You say the mp4 is 1.6MB - but your code says it is 59467 bytes. Does it work if you use the correct size? Also, can you upload the video directly on the Twitter website? If not, it may be that the file is corrupted.

Comment: When I try to use the correct size the APPEND commands throws an error after 59467 bytes. So I thought maybe I can compromise on the size a bit in order to test it. Yes, I've tried uploading the same video on twitter and it works perfectly.

Comment: You were right to doubt the video size handling. Posted what worked for me, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the actual size of the file instead of just a part of it and make sure you use a function to dynamically get the size. Static size does not work even if all the chunks get uploaded.